Age group VS age range VS age band VS age bracket
Do all four phrases mean exactly the same when filled in the following example?

Children in the ____ from 5 to 10 were quickly cured.

To me there's no difference at all. What do you think?

To me "bracket" sounds like the children were actively separated into groups (as in classes at school or teams in a sporting organization), where as "range" is more likely a statistical grouping.

These are valid phrases and mean the same.
Ngram
shows age group to be the most prevalent followed by age range, age bracket,  and then age band.  The first three are common phrases and are found in dictionaries; the last one is not found in major dictionaries.  The choice is yours.
